# Azure Service Bus Relay Occasional FaultException

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-servicebusrelay, basichttprelaybinding

We can't determine why the Azure **BasicHttpRelay** is throwing an occasional `FaultException` without any details. We've enabled WCF diagnostic tracing, but the available stack trace information is still the same. It seems like the WCF client channel fails for a brief time and then shortly returns.

We do cache the WCF Channel (*e.g. `CreateChannel`*), but this is the first time we've experienced this strange behavior. We have other Azure Service Bus relay solutions that work fine with this approach.

#### Error Message:

> There was an error encountered while processing the request.

#### Stack Trace:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at [our WCF method]...
```

#### FaultException - FaultCode Details:

> **Name:** ServerErrorFault 
> **Namespace:** http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2009/05/servicebus/relay 
> **IsPredefinedFault:** false 
> **IsReceiverFault:** false 
> **IsSenderFault:** false

#### Soap Message

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2009/05/servicebus/relay">a:ServerErrorFault</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">There was an error encountered while processing the request.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ServerErrorFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2009/05/servicebus/relay" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Through debugging, we can see the server properly responds to the message requests (*via IDispatchMessageInspector*), but the client fails to handle the response appropriately (*IClientMessageInspector reports fault*). Subsequent relay requests will succeed after the client channel seemingly *corrects* itself. These failures seem to be intermittent and not load-driven. We never see these `FaultException` errors using `basicHttpBinding` outside the Azure relay.

Does anyone have any suggestions? We are using **Azure SDK 1.8**.

I've tried configured a new **Service Bus Relay namespace** using `owner` shared secret, but still seeing the same results.

Comment: How often do these happen? They're not just randomly expected transient issues, are they?

Comment: They seem to behave like brief relay outages every 10-20 seconds - as multiple requests receive this error in a 2-3 second span, with only a single user load (*averaging 3 requests/sec*). The application pool never dies or recycles on the service hosting side - so it must be an issue with the relay itself.

Comment: I would suggest loading up the system to get some very consistent metrics. Does it happen every 10 seconds more-or-less exactly or is it random? Even if you don't have a clue what the source is, try to understand the behavior a little more so we can see the patterns and make educated guesses.

Comment: It would probably be best to contact support for this issue.

Comment: @TheDude - thanks for the tip! We did discover this to be a Microsoft bug with the Relay. They are currently working on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaching out to MS - this issue turned out to be an MS bug with the Relay or the SDK, specifically when using [**Http Connectivity Mode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitysettings.mode.aspx). At this point, the only workaround is ensure you have the [appropriate outgoing TCP ports opened up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706729.aspx) to ensure reliable connectivity with the Azure Relay.

**Allow [Outgoing TCP Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732535.aspx): 9350 - 9354**

MS has told us that they are still working on resolving the root cause. Hopefully this workaround will help others. Our corporate firewall had these TCP ports blocked which forced all communication over port 80 which must trigger this issue. The positive thing is that opening up these ports enables faster connectivity to the relay when starting up your listeners (*[AutoDetect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitysettings.mode.aspx) doesn't have to check the TCP ports availability every time*).